# IOS retrieve properties from an ABPerson

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook, abperson

I should retrieve/extract all the available properties of an ABPerson.
The official documentation for [IOS ABPerson](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)
Don't include the MACOS available method [ABPerson properties]

What can i do?

Comment: Try searching here on ABPerson - this topic has come up a huge number of times and code to do it is on this site already.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an NSArray/NSSet with all the properties found in the [ABPerson reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) under the **Personal Information Properties** header.

Then just use a for-in to go through the NSArray like so.

```
NSArray *allPropertiesForABPerson = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"kABPersonFirstNameProperty", @"kABPersonLastNameProperty", /*rest of props here*/, nil];

for (id property in allPropertiesForABPerson) {
  id valueForProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(theRecord, property);
  NSLog(@"Value: %@ for property: %@", valueForProperty, property);
  CFRelease(valueForProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an `ABPerson` called `myFriend`. You can access its first name by:

```
NSString* firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(myFriend, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Of course, you can replace `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` with other property constants to get other properties.

Here are some of them:

```
kABPersonFirstNameProperty
kABPersonLastNameProperty
kABPersonMiddleNameProperty
kABPersonPrefixProperty
kABPersonSuffixProperty
kABPersonNicknameProperty
kABPersonFirstNamePhoneticProperty
ckABPersonLastNamePhoneticProperty
kABPersonMiddleNamePhoneticProperty
kABPersonOrganizationProperty
kABPersonJobTitleProperty
kABPersonDepartmentProperty
kABPersonEmailProperty
kABPersonBirthdayProperty
kABPersonNoteProperty
kABPersonCreationDateProperty
kABPersonModificationDateProperty
```

More about ABPerson:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Personal_Information_Properties